# Android Lollipop Network API and OkHttp

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, okhttp, android-networking

I running into an issue routing network calls using OkHttp. I'm trying to send HTTP requests to a local device (via the device's ip) using an Access Point that has no internet access. Due to some changes in Android 5.0, OkHttp will try to route the request over data instead, which then fails.

In Android 5.0's Network API, I could use the `NetworkCapabilities` class along with the `NetworkRequest.Builder` in order to tell the request to only go over Wi-Fi, However, I'm already using OkHttp and I don't want to overhaul my code. Is there anyway to do a similar thing with OkHttp?

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a workaround:

```
final Network currentNetwork = (Network) network;
newClientBuilder.socketFactory(((Network)network).getSocketFactory())
    .dns(new Dns() {
          @Override
          public List<InetAddress> lookup(String hostname) throws UnknownHostException {
                        return Arrays.asList(currentNetwork.getAllByName(hostname));
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

We’d like to eventually include such functionality directly in OkHttp, and you might be the first volunteer/victim to test things out. What you probably want to do is use OkHttp 2.6’s new `Dns` interface to call through to the network of your choice. If that works, either the IP address will cause OkHttp to do the right thing anyway, or you’ll *also* need to replace the `SocketFactory`.

Comment: I'm not sure how I would use the `Dns` interface to call through to the network of my choice, could you give me an example of how to use it?

Comment: Implement the interface, and implement lookup() to call through to getAllByName().

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I've been dealing with other bugs on the app I'm working on. As clarification, the hostname I am passing to the `OkHttpClient` is just the ip of the device. When I call getAllByName() it only returns one `InetAddress`. Using that address on it's own hasn't fixed the problem. If I replace the `SocketFactory` I would just have to implement the methods to create a socket that connects straight to the ip, right? How is that different from OkHttp's default behavior?